# iptables nat table is not changing destination IP in PREROUTING?

Tags: iptables, dnat

OK, so on a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.2 install, i run the following commands:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"'
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.196.106.230
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo -n
```

​
Then i ping `192.168.100.1` from another terminal. But, i see `tcpdump` showing me this:

```
01:46:37.536354 IP 10.196.100.76 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 6635, seq 1, length 64
```

​

However, if i flush the nat table and run [this command](https://serverfault.com/a/124196/313325) instead:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.100.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.196.106.230
```

Then, `tcpdump` gives this:

```
01:46:53.168639 IP 10.196.100.76 > 10.196.106.230: ICMP echo request, id 6638, seq 1, length 64
```

(The ping is successful, with a pong coming back from the other machine.)

From the [numerous tutorials](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html) online, i'd expect the destination IP to be changed even in the PREROUTING chain, right? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PREROUTING chain is not evaluated on packets generated by local processes.

Your first rule will work on packet entering from a network interface (try to ping from a different computer).

Maybe this picture can clarify how the flow of packets is examined: [image: Packet filtering in iptables]

source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables.html